# Extjs editable grid pushing rows away

Tags: grid, extjs4

I'm currently working on an extjs editable grid. The code was partially copied from the documentation in order to understand how to use this type of grid properly. This is the code:

```
Ext.define('GestioneScadenza', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['codiceRamo', 'denominazione', {name: 'dataScadenza', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'} ]
});

var gestioneScadenzaStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'GestioneScadenza',
    data: [
        { codiceRamo: 'Lisa', denominazione: 'lisa@simpsons.com', dataScadenza: '03/03/1999' },
        { codiceRamo: 'Bart', denominazione: 'bart@simpsons.com', dataScadenza: '03/03/1999' },
        { codiceRamo: 'Homer', denominazione: 'homer@simpsons.com', dataScadenza: '03/03/1999' },
        { codiceRamo: 'Marge', denominazione: 'marge@simpsons.com', dataScadenza: '03/03/1999' }
    ]
});


var gestioneScadenzaGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: gestioneScadenzaStore,
    plugins: [
              Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                  clicksToEdit: 1
              })
          ],
          listeners:{
              'beforeedit':function(editor){
                  editor.getEditor().floatingButtons.hide();
              }},
    columns: [
        {
            flex: 5,
            text: getJsResource('tabRami.label.codiceRamo'),
//            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'codiceRamo'
        },
        {
            flex: 2,
            text: getJsResource('tabRami.label.denominazione'),
//            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'denominazione'
        },
        {
            flex: 3,
            text: getJsResource('tabRami.label.dataScadenza'),
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
//            width: 135,
            dataIndex: 'dataScadenza',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: false,
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                maxValue: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'd/m/Y')
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

My problem with this code is that it only displays one column! In fact, the other columns are pushed away from the page and I have to scroll a lot to reach the end of the grid. It seems like the problem is flex. In fact, if I only put a value of flex for the last item, it will correctly show the columns, but the last one will be pushed very far laterally.

Any solutions?

Comment: What is your grid's container (grid's parent component) layout? And you see just the first column of this grid (others are beyond the browser's viewport)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. The issue could be due to some other code.

You can try isolating this piece of code to check.

You may want to check the [sample fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lg2) to help you troubleshoot.